# JupyterHub single user kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

Is it possible in JupyterHub that regardless of the user logged in, a kernel (e.g. Python) will always run with a specific user?

I think it might be possible with container-based Spawners (e.g. KubeSpawner or DockerSpawner), but not sure if LocalProcessSpawner can do it or if there is some configuration to the kernel.json that will allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Have you tried [SimpleLocalProcessSpawner](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/3800ceaf9edf33a0171922b93ea3d94f87aa8d91/jupyterhub/spawner.py#L1647)?  If I remember correctly, it use the same $USER(same $USER who starts the hub) to run the kernel regardless which user is signing in.  I personally use this for the integration tests, which works really well for me.

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround regardless that in the comments it clearly states: DO NOT USE THIS FOR PRODUCTION USE CASES!